# android: How to create new Activity with a different name with a click of a button?

Tags: android, listview, android-activity

I have an Activity with ListView EditText and a Button. What I'm struggling to do is when adding new Item to the ListView with the EditText's context, I want to make that new Item click able and have direct me to a new Activity with an already built UI.

1. Beside the first Activity with the three views, I already have the second Activity that I want to recreate each time I press the button in the first Activity.
2. I used ArrayList and ArrayAdapter to add new Items to the ListView but don't know how to make the new Items click able and have them direct me to a new Activity with with the UI of the second Activity I created.

Edit: 
Basically what I'm trying to make is a sort of contact list, and what I can't figure is how when you click New for New Contact and it pop up a window with fields to fill and then (after the user confirm) it add the New Contact to a ListView of all contacts and when pressing a contact's name it open a new window with the contact info.

Comment: why do you want to create a new activity?  do you mean you want to launch the second activity with new criteria specific to the listItem clicked?

Comment: Yes. I edited my message so please check that out to better understand what I'm trying to make. I thought of making a the second class a custom view instead of Activity, but I was told that it would not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this:

```
ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<>(); //dummy data
ArrayList<String> tels = new ArrayList<>(); //dummy data
names.add("peter");  //dummy data
tels.add("12334567"); //dummy data
names.add("mary");  //dummy data
tels.add("345343637"); //dummy data
//you should get the data from your own list!!!

listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int pos, long id) {

            Intent i = new Intent(CurrentClass.this, NextClass.class);
            i.putExtra("name", names.get(pos) );
            i.putExtra("tel", tels.get(pos) );
            startActivity(i);
        }
}
```

In the NextClass.class

```
   Intent intent= getIntent();
   String name = intent.getStringExtra("name");
   String tel = intent.getStringExtra("tel");
```

Comment: Sorry for not responding for so long. Was busy with work and studies... In regard to the answers I received, thanks, but sending the info to the second Activity is not my problem. After filling info and adding a new contact to my list, what I struggle with is to make the name of the new contact click-able (You kinda already answered that) and have it send me to the second Activity, and being able to do it with every contact I add. In what kind of a loop do I need to put the second Activity for it to be compatible  with the new name in the list and so on and so on...?

Comment: why do you need a loop? you want the name and tel to be editable in the second activity?

Comment: No. I want them to be presented in the second activity when I click the new Item in the list.

Comment: in my answer, you already got the `name` and `tel` in string format, you only need to set them to the textview, 
`myTextView.setText("name : " + name);`
`myTextView.setText("tel : " + tel);`

Comment: @user3395989 do you find you answer here?

Answer (score 0):

```
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {

            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SecondActivity.class);
           /*note you can use i.putExtra(tag,value); to add as many item specific variable you want your second activity to handle*/ 
            startActivity(i);

        }
}
```